# How to create stack vertical listview and horizontal listview in flutter draggablescrollablesheet?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a horizontallistview inside a verticalistview which is part of draggablescrollablesheet, confused? Basically I'm trying to create something similar to this page [Horizontal ListView inside a Vertical ScrollView in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512171/horizontal-listview-inside-a-vertical-scrollview-in-flutter), but inside a draggablescrollablesheet. So far I keep on running to errors from incorrectparentwidget to unbounded height problems, I tried searching everywhere but no solutions so far if anyone can help that would be helpful. Here is the code

main.dart

```
    class Weather extends StatefulWidget {
  const Weather({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WeatherState createState() => _WeatherState();
}

class _WeatherState extends State<Weather> {
  late image_switch testing;
  late time_identifier time;

  late weather_screen_data data_weather;
  late weather_data weather;//the method to get the variable below
  late String iconurl;
  late String image;
  late String timeofday;
  late String year;
  late String weekdate;
  late String weekday;
  late String month;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    testing = image_switch();
    time = time_identifier();
    initializeDateFormatting();
    testing.check_time();
    setState(() {
      timeofday = time.time_switcher();
      image = testing.image_switcher();
      year = time.year();
      weekdate = time.weekdate();
      weekday = time.weekday();
      month = time.month();
    });
  }
  Future<weather_screen_data> data= weather_data.get_data();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder<weather_screen_data>(
          future: data,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<weather_screen_data> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: [
                  Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(image),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                BlendMode.darken),
                          )),
                      child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.h, left: 11.w),
                                child: Text("Selamat $timeofday, Dwika",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.sp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ))),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 310.h, left: 23.w),
                                child: Text("${snapshot.data!.description.variable}",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 48.sp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ))),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.h, left: 23.w),
                                child: Text(weekday,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 34.sp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ))),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.h, left: 23.w),
                                child: Text("$weekdate $month",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 34.sp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ))),
                            Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 22.h, left: 23.w),
                                child: Text("$year",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 34.sp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    )))
                          ])),
                  Positioned(
                    top:82.h,
                    left:12.w,
                    child: Container(
                        width: 160.w,
                        height: 160.w,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image:NetworkImage("http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + snapshot.data!.icon.variable + ".png"),
                              fit:BoxFit.cover),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 220.h,
                    left: 12.w,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text("${snapshot.data!.temprature.variable.round()}°",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 96, color: Colors.white)),
                        Text("C",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 96,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                      top: 21.h,
                      right: 30.w,
                      child: IconButton(
                        iconSize: 40.sp,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                        onPressed: () {
                          time_identifier().generate_days();
                          setState(() {
                            data=weather_data.get_data();
                            testing.check_time();
                            image = testing.image_switcher();
                            timeofday = time.time_switcher();
                            image = testing.image_switcher();
                            year = time.year();
                            weekdate = time.weekdate();
                            weekday = time.weekday();
                            month = time.month();
                          });
                        },
                      )),
                  bottomsheet()
                ]);
            }else{
              return Center(
                child:CircularProgressIndicator()
              );
            }
          }
          ));
  }
}
```

just focus on the part where I put the bottomsheet, you can ignore the other parts

bottomsheet.dart

```
class bottomsheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const bottomsheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _bottomsheetState createState() => _bottomsheetState();
}

class _bottomsheetState extends State<bottomsheet> {
  @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   // days=time_identifier().generate_days();
  //   setState(() {
  //     days=time_identifier().generate_days();
  //   });
  // }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> days = time_identifier().generate_days();
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize:0.06,
        minChildSize:0.05,
        maxChildSize:0.8,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController)
    {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
              topRight: Radius.circular(50),
            )
        ),
        child: ListView.builder(itemCount:5,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children:[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(shrinkWrap:true,
                      scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,itemCount:5,itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
                    return Text("Hello World");
                  }),
                )
              ]),
            );
        },)

      );},
    );
  }
  }
```

As you can see I have tried everything in the book, wrapping the widget with Expanded, and then using Columns, shrinkwrap,etc but it always gives me incorrect ParentWidget Use or unbounded height problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fidgeting around it turns out I have to wrap my ListView.builder inside a container so it becomes like this in the bottomsheet.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../weather/time_identifier.dart';

class bottomsheet extends StatefulWidget {
  const bottomsheet({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _bottomsheetState createState() => _bottomsheetState();
}

class _bottomsheetState extends State<bottomsheet> {
  @override
  // void initState() {
  //   super.initState();
  //   // days=time_identifier().generate_days();
  //   setState(() {
  //     days=time_identifier().generate_days();
  //   });
  // }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> days = time_identifier().generate_days();
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize:0.06,
        minChildSize:0.05,
        maxChildSize:0.8,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController)
    {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
              topRight: Radius.circular(50),
            )
        ),
        child: ListView.builder(controller: scrollController,itemCount:5,itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return
            Container(
              height:200,
              child: ListView.builder(shrinkWrap:true,
                  scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,itemCount:10,itemBuilder:(BuildContext context, int index){
                return Text("Hello World");
              }),
            );
        },)

      );},
    );
  }
  }
```