# How to use Listview.builder in Column and make them scrollable horizontally in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: code]

Is there any way to use SingleChildScrollView and pass Column as a child and ListView.builder in that column?

I just want something like shown in the attached photo.

Comment: Why do you want a ListView in the Column?

Comment: Have you tried using Slivers? It'll also help if you could provide an image of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to make a screen that is scrollable horizontally. It consists of some text in the center and after that, a horizontal row is displayed that acts as a heading of the next rows that are fetched from API.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do what you aim to do is the Scrollable Widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable-class.html

Another way is to set the `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal`  https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list

From the code you post I think you are aiming to something like this
[Horizontal ListView inside a Vertical ScrollView in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54512171/horizontal-listview-inside-a-vertical-scrollview-in-flutter)

Comment: I have used it but the issue is it is not solving my problem. The issue is to use SingleChildScrollView with Column and a ListView.builder inside that column.

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: How to post code because it's too long and exceeds the limit of characters?

Comment: You can cut the part not useful and show us only some content, maybe it is not executable but it shows the workflow

Comment: Kindly see the edited post, I attached a code photo. I want something like the attached photo. 
Sample Code:
SingleChildScrollView(
child:Column(
children[
ListView.builder()
]))

Comment: could you share an UI example of what you want to achieve? your explanation is not clear

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by passing the ListView.builder widget in an Expanded widget. A listview already has a SingleChildScrollview feature, You can easily remove it. and replace it with Expanded Widget [a link to the code snippet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7ctE.png).